# I'm writing a localization project with C# WPF, but it does not work when creating installer file Localization Project

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, installation

I'm writing a localization project with C# WPF, but it does not work when creating installer file Localization Project.
After installing and starting the program, it did not change the localization, like changing the language
For example, a language selector is placed in a combo box, but the change will not change the language.
But when the installation file for it is not made yet, while in Debug or Release mode, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case msi installer didn't include all files needed for localization. That were files bin\<language>\<assembly name>.resources.dll. Once I added them localization started work well after installation.